# How can I set a view not to use the path previously set and be able to save the view?

Tags: views

I have some views I am not currently using. I want to disable the path, or leave it as *No path is set*.

All I get is the following message.

> Display "VIEW" uses a path but the path is undefined.

How can I set a view not to use the path previously set and be able to save the view?

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the view by going to 
Structure -> views 
Inside views on the right side there will be a tab and when u click on it you can disable the view so that you can enable it for future use.

Comment: can you please post with image, so that it will more clear and don't use short form for words.

Comment: ok, i will post image

Answer (score 0):

[image: Use the dropdown on the right to disable the view]

Use the dropdown on the right to disable the view